# IntelliJ 2017 cannot run program java when connecting to Datasource

Tags: java, intellij-idea, datasource, h2

**Problem Description:**
When adding new `Datasource` in Intellij 2017 and clicking `Test Connection` the error occurs: `cannot find program ${INTELLIJ_HOME}\jre64\bin\java`, see below screen shot.

**Observations:**

1. Regualar code compilation works, project can be launched successfully
2. It is not related with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238144/in-intellij-idea-14-1-4-cannot-run-program-c-program-files-x86-java-jdk1-8), even tough, proposed solutaion was already verified and did not helped.
3. This only affects adding new Datasource in Datasource tab.
4. None of other datasources can be added in the Datasource tab, either Postgres, and so on.
5. The application serving the H2 in memory DB is stareted and connected to it.

Did someone experienced similar problems when adding new datasource?

[image: IntelliJ 2017 error screen shot]

Comment: Did you noticed the path is sying programy? I think this is quite not right for a windows system if not done manually

Comment: Unfortonately that would be too easy, the path is correct. By the way this is Polish word standing for "Programs" :)

Comment: okay just wanted to be sure as I'm quite not familar with other languages path names.

Comment: Just guessing into the blue: Have you checked the correctness of path in project settings -> SDK ?

Comment: yes, it points to totally other path `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`, yet the IntelliJ is still looking for its internal JRE, for some reason.

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOME set to a JDK?

Comment: ```echo %JAVA_HOME% ->
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159752/discussion-between-lostkatana-and-devdio).