# IntelliJ - Cannot run program java.exe. CreateProcess error=2. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I'm reaching out for a bit of help in trying to figure out why my IntelliJ does not run for a project.

I am using IntelliJ 2023.1.5 Community Edition Build #IC-231.9392.1, built on July 25, 2023

I have multiple projects all but one running jdk 1.8.0 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java, all were working fine until I started a new project using corretto 17.0.7, which was initially placed here C:\Users\Me.jdks\jbr-17.0.7\bin\java.exe, but is now in the Java folder with the previously mentioned jdk

The new project was working as it should, then I needed to swap back to one of the other projects. At this point when I try to run the older project I get the following error:

*Cannot run program "C:\Users\Me\.jdks\jbr-17.0.7\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2023.1\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.*

This error occurred both before and after the directory change of corretto 17.0.7, it never occurred prior to the creation of the new project

I have went through my older project and there is nothing referencing 17.0.7 that I can see, in the places where I know a jdk can be set

*Project Settings - Project*
[image: Project Settings - Project]

*Project Settings - Modules*
[image: Project Settings - Modules]

*Project Settings - SDKs*
[image: Project Settings - SDKs]

*Run/Debug Config*
[image: Run/Debug Config]

The below 2 do show a different JDK to the one I'm using, I'm not entirely sure it matters as I haven't changed them and the older project used to work fine prior to the new one being started.

*Java Runtime Environment*
[image: Java Runtime Environment]

*Java Registry*
[image: Java Registry]

Other things I have tried
Invalidate the cache of IntelliJ, reboot the machine

Trying to find the cause/solution led to to also try
Adding the -Didea.dynamic.classpath=true in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and restart the IDE - Did not work (Part of this question [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-285090](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com))

As per this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238144/in-intellij-idea-14-1-4-cannot-run-program-c-program-files-x86-java-jdk1-8](https://stackoverflow.com) the answer asks
If your path JAVA_HOME is OK:

File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Maven → Runner
Set to "use JAVA_HOME (...Path...)"
[image: Maven Runner]
This is set to the jdk path albeit not JAVA_HOME, I did try adding a JAVA_HOME Environment Variable here but no change so deleted it out.

For Part 2 of the answer, I do not have a File → Other Settings → Default Project Structure to check

The older project works on other machines fine, a second user also configured their machine to use my new project and they can swap between the new and old project with no issues.

So I guess my question would be based on the error message I get when trying to run the older program - What could have been changed to it now be causing it to look here for the java.exe ("C:\Users\Me\.jdks\jbr-17.0.7\bin\java.exe"), when I didn't do anything to the older programs setup ?

I cannot for the life of me figure out what the solution is, hence why I am coming here to see if anyone else can provide assistance.

Comment: I don't use the IDE but [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/specifying-compilation-settings.html) comes up when searching that file not found path. Maybe you should regenerate your compiler settings?

Comment: Please see if https://stackoverflow.com/a/59023270/12844632 helps

Comment: @EgorKlepikov Thanks for this, that was another article I looked at but trying what was suggested did not work for me

Comment: It really seems like you have removed a version of java 1.8 and then are trying to use it. In your project settings you have 171 but everywhere else you have 272. Is this a maven project?

Comment: I would probably begin by removing any SDK in the IDE (you seem to have tons) that refers to a non-existent jdk

Comment: @g00se My compiler settings are setup the same as another machine which works. I do not see a way to regenerate these. I do have it clearing the output directory and rebuilding on dependency change, not sure what else in here if anything would help.

Comment: I've just given you a 'no-lose' suggestion. You could even remove *all* SDKs and re-add ones for existing JDKs only

Comment: @g00se, Removing the unused sdk's seems to have got the older project back up and running, but broke the newer one. So just trying to fix that one now

Comment: Well, by the looks (it's confusing), you don't currently even have a JDK installed that's modern enough to handle a module-based project, if that's what you've got...

Comment: @g00se It's been that way since the project started, so I just work with it.  But both projects are up and running now, so there was definitely some conflicts surrounding the sdk's

Comment: @g00se The screenshot lists 3 Java 17 versions (Coretto, IntelliJ's built-in Java 17 and one other), not all Java installers from all Java vendors write those registry entries.

Comment: @g00se, Can you make your comment about removing the SDK as an answer.
For other that commented on this appreciate your time looking at this and providing a response

Comment: Will do. @MarkRotteveel , what about the "Java Runtime Environment" control applet? It shows three old JREs

Comment: @g00se As far as I'm aware, that is no longer supported since Java 9, and again, might only lists Oracle's JVMs, and not from other vendors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably begin by removing any SDK in the IDE (you seem to have tons) that refers to a non-existent jdk. You really need to synch what you have installed with what your IDE says it can deliver

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 1.8 then keep only that in "SDKs" in platform settings of IntelliJ. Remove remaining JDK's like 1.7, 17, jbr-17, correto-17 and so on.

I also faced the same issue when I am using 1.8 and selected 1.8 only everywhere, still I got the error. Then I removed "jbr-17" from SDK's in platform settings. Then it worked fine.